# Forced GC.Collect in Asp.net CMS website

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, performance, iis-7

This is the situation

I am working on a **Content Management System** where we have two parts first is admin side from where admin users can fill contents and second is user side from where users can see the content provided by admin from the admin panel.

If a user is browsing my website he only visits those pages which do only one thing, They pull the content from database according to the page and shows that content to the user.

The problem is when I run my website in my local IIS and browse it for some time and track the memory usage by the IIS worker process (w3wp.exe) is shows **109,292 K** at peak usage.

So to solve this I put this code in my **global.asax** file

```
void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  GC.Collect(0, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
  GC.Collect(1, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
  GC.Collect(2, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
}
```

After this the usage drop to **75,980 K** at peak usage.

The question is **am I doing right thing here ?** because I read many articles which say that I should not perform this `GC.Collect`.

**Update**
At real environment this is the situation whithout any `GC.Collect()`

[image]

Comment: 109,292K is really not much memory on IIS you should care about, intercepting CG might may slow down the performance

Comment: @CuongLe but that was just one user me browsing the site, what will happen on live environment ?

Comment: I think you should review your code and dispose objects properly before resorting to a forced GC collect.

Comment: I am afraid that I don't understand much your question?

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure this is an *actual* problem? Have you tried multiple concurrent accesses and seen you have a memory issue?

100MB of memory is not a lot, so the garbage collector doesn't bother with it. If your process will require more memory, the garbage collector will start doing its job.

You almost never need to perform a forced garbage collection, most of the times you'll do more harm than good. This is one of those times - you'll do very little in terms of memory consumption, but on the other your performance will suffer - garbage collections are costly, and you're running one every time a request is done.

So in short, drop the forced garbage collections and only worry about it when you see there's an actual problem.

Comment: +1... although I think the issue of not reviewing the code base first needs addressing. Jumping straight to a forced GC is quite treacherous..

Comment: His code is probably fine, after garbage collection he ends up with 80MB, which is *very* reasonable for IIS. If he had a *major* memory leak, he wouldn't have seen this behavior (it's just quite impossible to detect a small memory leak when he checks just one request)

Comment: @zmbq can you please point out some common issues in your answer which could be causing this memory consumption issue. or some links to good articles.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. I'm saying you *probably don't* have a memory consumption issue. You need to test your application under real load before you can say that.

Comment: @zmbq So you mean with one user it's complicated, But what if I get huge memory consumption with many users at live environment, Is then that `GC.Collect` fine according to you ??

Comment: Again, is it a problem? How many concurrent connections can you handle? When you add more connections, is your bottleneck memory consumption or something else? How much memory do you have on your machine?

Comment: @zmbq I agree with you, what I mean is that there is a process issue here because the OP has immediately started forcing garbage collections instead of troubleshooting it properly/researching the issue.

Comment: @zmbq I might be missing something , but does gc.collect in asp.net runs through *all* applications roots , or only roots for the user/thread that called gc.collect ?